# Tkinter - text inserted into text box appears backwards

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm currently attempting to write a calculator in Tkinter. So far, I have managed to place all the buttons and add functionality to some buttons (numbers 0-9, the "+" button and the "clear" button) but I am struggling because when a simple equation is input into my calculator. For example, 11-1 - the text that appears in the window is backwards, and my program reads it backwards, and will evaluate 1-11.

Here's the code. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

window_width = 200
window_height = 300

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')

def clear_text():
    entry_box.delete(0, END)

def print_one():
    entry_box.insert(0, "1")

def print_two():
    entry_box.insert(0, "2")

def print_three():
    entry_box.insert(0, "3")

def print_four():
    entry_box.insert(0, "4")

def print_five():
    entry_box.insert(0, "5")

def print_six():
    entry_box.insert(0, "6")

def print_seven():
    entry_box.insert(0, "7")

def print_eight():
    entry_box.insert(0, "8")

def print_nine():
    entry_box.insert(0, "9")

def print_zero():
    entry_box.insert(0, "0")

def print_plus():
    entry_box.insert(0, "+")

def print_minus():
    entry_box.insert(0, "-")

def print_divide():
    entry_box.insert(0, "/")

def print_multiply():
    entry_box.insert(0, "*")

def do_maths():
    equation = entry_box.get()
    evaluate_equation = eval(equation)
    entry_box.delete(0, END)
    entry_box.insert(0, evaluate_equation)

simple_calculator = Label(root,text="Simple Calculator").place(x=30, y=10)

entry_text = StringVar()
entry_box = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)

one = Button(root, text="1", command=print_one).place(x=30,y=50)
two = Button(root, text="2", command=print_two).place(x=60, y=50)
three = Button(root, text="3", command=print_three).place(x=90, y=50)
four = Button(root, text="4", command=print_four).place(x=30, y=80)
five = Button(root, text="5", command=print_five).place(x=60, y=80)
six = Button(root, text="6", command=print_six).place(x=90, y=80)
seven = Button(root, text="7", command=print_seven).place(x=30, y=110)
eight = Button(root, text="8", command=print_eight).place(x=60, y=110)
nine = Button(root, text="9", command=print_nine).place(x=90, y=110)
zero = Button(root, text="0", command=print_zero).place(x=30, y=140)
plus = Button(root, text="+", command=print_plus).place(x=60, y=140)
minus = Button(root, text="-", command=print_minus).place(x=90, y=140)
divide = Button(root, text="/", command=print_divide).place(x=30, y=170)
multiply = Button(root, text="*", command=print_multiply).place(x=60, y=170)
equals = Button(root, text="=", command=do_maths).place(x=90, y=170)
clear = Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear_text).place(x=30, y=200)

entry_box.place(x=30, y=230)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

so in your program , you're inserting each value(numbers and equations) at the index of 0 which means you are inserting them at the start of the entry_box , what you need to do is to insert each value at the **'END'** of the entry_box

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

window_width = 200
window_height = 300

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')

def clear_text():
    entry_box.delete(0, END)

def print_one():
    entry_box.insert(END, "1")

def print_two():
    entry_box.insert(END, "2")

def print_three():
    entry_box.insert(END, "3")

def print_four():
    entry_box.insert(END, "4")

def print_five():
    entry_box.insert(END, "5")

def print_six():
    entry_box.insert(END, "6")

def print_seven():
    entry_box.insert(END, "7")

def print_eight():
    entry_box.insert(END, "8")

def print_nine():
    entry_box.insert(END, "9")

def print_zero():
    entry_box.insert(END, "0")

def print_plus():
    entry_box.insert(END, "+")

def print_minus():
    entry_box.insert(END, "-")

def print_divide():
    entry_box.insert(END, "/")

def print_multiply():
    entry_box.insert(END, "*")

def do_maths():
    equation = entry_box.get()
    evaluate_equation = eval(equation)
    entry_box.delete(0, END)
    entry_box.insert(0, evaluate_equation)

simple_calculator = Label(root,text="Simple Calculator").place(x=30, y=10)

entry_text = StringVar()
entry_box = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)

one = Button(root, text="1", command=print_one).place(x=30,y=50)
two = Button(root, text="2", command=print_two).place(x=60, y=50)
three = Button(root, text="3", command=print_three).place(x=90, y=50)
four = Button(root, text="4", command=print_four).place(x=30, y=80)
five = Button(root, text="5", command=print_five).place(x=60, y=80)
six = Button(root, text="6", command=print_six).place(x=90, y=80)
seven = Button(root, text="7", command=print_seven).place(x=30, y=110)
eight = Button(root, text="8", command=print_eight).place(x=60, y=110)
nine = Button(root, text="9", command=print_nine).place(x=90, y=110)
zero = Button(root, text="0", command=print_zero).place(x=30, y=140)
plus = Button(root, text="+", command=print_plus).place(x=60, y=140)
minus = Button(root, text="-", command=print_minus).place(x=90, y=140)
divide = Button(root, text="/", command=print_divide).place(x=30, y=170)
multiply = Button(root, text="*", command=print_multiply).place(x=60, y=170)
equals = Button(root, text="=", command=do_maths).place(x=90, y=170)
clear = Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear_text).place(x=30, y=200)

entry_box.place(x=30, y=230)

root.mainloop()
```

here I just changed the indexes in each insert from 0 to END

> END represents the point immediately after the last character entered
> by the user

Comment: what is the point of `entry_box.delete(END, END)`?

Comment: @Aeen pressed button to replace all, He forgot about it. Same as I did.

Comment: @acw1668 yep didnt notice that, just corrected my answer! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `.insert()` statements are set to index `0` so the characters are placed at the beginning of `entry_box`. You can change all of your functions according to the pattern below.

```py
def print_one():
    entry_box.insert(len(entry_text.get()), "1")
```

Comment: len(entry_text.get() is basicly the samething as the constant END

Comment: Better to use `entry_box.insert('end', "1")`